# SpEL getMethod don't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

suppose I have a class foo.PoJo which has a static public method String， according to the [offical reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/spel.html),this piece of code should return a Method instance.

```
SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("T(foo.PoJo).getMethod('print')");
Method m = (Method) exp.getValue();
```

However, this code would raise a exception:

```
  Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 49): Method call: Method getMethod(java.lang.String) cannot be found on foo
.PoJo type
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:185)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:107)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:93)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:66)
        at com.duowan.realtime.scheduled.batch.temp.PoJo.main(PoJo.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

My guess is that the T() operation will return a Class object,so you can access the static method and field of this object, however the Method getMethod(String name, Class... parameterTypes) function is only a public method not static, so the exception raised.
If I was right the reference may need an update. Anybody has any idea?

Comment: The code you've posted works for me with Spring 4.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T()` actually returns the class instance and you can access static methods declared on `Foo` itself. In Java you would have to use `Foo.class.getMethod()`.

It looks like Spring added support for accessing class methods in 3.1; I only get your failure when using 3.0.x.

The current Spring Framework release is 4.1.0.

EDIT:

[Confirmed - Fixed in 3.1.3](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9017).